# How do I add add urlacl to already used 443 port?

Tags: acl, netsh

I am trying to give uralacl to my user ad\user running this command:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:443/ user=ad\user
```

but getting this error: 
Url reservation add failed, Error: 183
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

then I run this command and see that if it is already used:

```
netsh http show url
```

And I see that it is already reserved, probably by IIS:

Reserved URL: https://+:443/sra_{BA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0A
DCD75}/
User: NT SERVICE\SstpSvc
Listen: Yes
            Delegate: Yes
        User: BUILTIN\Administrators
            Listen: No
            Delegate: No
        User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: Yes
            SDDL: D:(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-80-3435701886-799518250-3791383489-3228296122
-2938884314)(A;;GR;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;SY)

I do not want to add my user to administrators.

So my question is: can I add my user to this urlacl somehow without deleting and then adding it?
So that in result urlacl is the same but including my user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not reusing the port... it's reusing the port with the same protocol.  Http.sys doesn't allow you to listen to https and http on the same port (I have not seen a service that supports this nor have I ever seen a need for this, although I suppose you could try to make one yourself with TCP sockets).  It seems like MS is trying to enforce that limitation within the urlacl.  This sort of makes sense.  If two applications attempt to open connections using two different protocols, which protocol should http.sys use?

Note that if you instead add another https url to port 443 there is no issue (as long as the path of the URL is different from the existing record).  It's a shame the error message from netsh does not explain more.

Comment: I didn't find much documentation to support this answer, so if someone finds documentation or disagrees please edit/comment.

Comment: thanks, you are absolutely right, there was an issue in my post, I should have changed url=http:// to url=https://